# How can I make shortcut text for long URLs in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, url-shortening

How can I make shortcut text for long URLs in Firefox and Chrome?

For example, I want to open `http://gmail.com` simply by typing `mail` in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can also use the Search Engines feature.

1. Right-click the address bar and then click **Edit search engines**.

   [image]
2. Type a name for your search engine.
3. Assign a keyword for it. In your case, use **mail**.
4. Enter your URL.

[image]

In this example, to open `https://www.gmail.com`, I just type `mail` in the address bar then press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Nithin is correct. Setting the keyword in firefox bookmarks would allow you to do this. 
Here's a good article about doing that.

http://lifehacker.com/248451/power-up-firefox-with-keywords

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and chrome will do this for you, in two ways

If you type `gmail` and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the browser will add the http://www prefix and the .com suffix.

After you have visited gmail enough times, the browser will auto-suggest the site after you have typed `gm`

You can make a bookmark and show it on the bookmarks toolbar at the top of the browser window.

[image: chrome bookmark bar]

If this isn't enough, you can create a desktop shortcut for any URL.

Comment: I just given gmail for example

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can make a bookmark and set the `Keyword` property to what you want. In this case `mail`. For Chrome, you can use RedGrittyBrick's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm there was a setting/3rd party utility in Internet Explorer years ago. I'll explain with examples:

g searh keywords

This is for Google search. Plus Chrome sense the site that you want to go at very first character, when you type g, it automatically complete the rest, try to add Gmail in your favs.

Personally I use  Chrome shortcut bar:

[image]